# Is there any way to use the Facebook API for reading user messages?

Tags: facebook, rest, facebook-graph-api, oauth

Previously, all I ever needed to read user messages from Facebook's Graph API was a request like this:
`https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/me/inbox&access_token=12345678` and I would be able to read from that endpoint as long as I had the `read_mailbox` permission. However, since they released Graph API v2.4, that permission seems to no longer exist. I was wondering if there was presently any other way to read Facebook messages, or if this functionality has effectively been removed?

Answer (score 1):

Since the permission got removed, there is no way to get access to the user inbox anymore. I am pretty sure it will stay that way, for very good reasons: Privacy of users who did not authorize the App.

Comment: Permissions were made specifically to allow for a user to have privacy. It's very annoying to have this permission killed off with literally no warning when your app is based off of reading Messenger messages.

Comment: actually, you did not get it approved since more than a year, so it was obvious that they would remove it sooner or later.